# Abstract classes for plugins and workflows

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2016

I have created the two following abstract classes that I use in my plugins and workflows:

```
/// <summary>
/// Base plugin class. Provides access to most often used Xrm resources.
/// </summary>
public abstract class BasePlugin : IPlugin
{

    public IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }
    public ITracingService TracingService { get; set; }
    public IPluginExecutionContext PluginContext { get; set; }
    public IOrganizationService Service { get; set; }

    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        ServiceProvider = serviceProvider;
        TracingService =
            (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

        PluginContext = (IPluginExecutionContext)
            serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

        IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
        Service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(PluginContext.UserId);

        ExecutePluginLogic();
    }

    public virtual void ExecutePluginLogic()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And

```
/// <summary>
/// Base workflow class. Provides access to most often used Xrm resources.
/// </summary>
public abstract class BaseWorkflow : CodeActivity
{
    public CodeActivityContext CodeActivityContext { get; set; }
    public IWorkflowContext WorkflowContext { get; set; }
    public ITracingService TracingService { get; set; }
    public IOrganizationService Service { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = context.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
        CodeActivityContext = context;
        TracingService = context.GetExtension<ITracingService>();
        WorkflowContext = context.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
        Service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(WorkflowContext.UserId);

        ExecuteWorkflowLogic();
    }

    public virtual void ExecuteWorkflowLogic()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }     
}
```

Here's how I would create a plugin then:

```
public class CalculateTaxesOnUpdate : BasePlugin
{

    public override void ExecutePluginLogic()
    {
        //From there I don't need to instanciate anything...neat!
    }
}
```

This seems to work fine and helps to reduce boiler plate code when it comes to initiating instances of `IOrganizationService` and `ITracingService` namely.

But I've noticed that on some messages (ie: `Update` of `invoicedetail`) that are triggered with short delays, on the first execution, public properties of `BasePlugin` are `null` (which is expected) then on the following executions, they are already initiated (??). I noticed this being an issue because I had a `Dispose` method in the base classes which would set properties to null after executing `ExecutePluginLogic` and other threads would then try to use `null` properties.

Since I'm not reusing them and re-initiating them anyways (which is what happens when you instanciate everything in `Execute` anyways), I don't know if that's an issue, but am I going against best practices here ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just because it is a base class doesn't eliminate the issue with class level variables in CRM plugins (and workflows.)

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328263.aspx#bkmk_writingbasic:

> For improved performance, Microsoft Dynamics CRM caches plug-in
>   instances. The plug-in's Execute method should be written to be
>   stateless because the constructor is not called for every invocation
>   of the plug-in. Also, multiple system threads could execute the
>   plug-in at the same time. All per invocation state information is
>   stored in the context, so you should not use global variables or
>   attempt to store any data in member variables for use during the next
>   plug-in invocation unless that data was obtained from the
>   configuration parameter provided to the constructor. Changes to a
>   plug-ins registration will cause the plug-in to be re-initialized.

Having class level variables violates this stateless requirement.

My recommendation is to rewrite the plugin (and then do the same for the workflow) to have an object that holds the references for each call to `Execute`, thus allowing the code to meet the stateless requirement.

```
public class CrmObjects
{
    public IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }
    public ITracingService TracingService { get; set; }
    public IPluginExecutionContext PluginContext { get; set; }
    public IOrganizationService Service { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BasePlugin : IPlugin
{

    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {

        var crmObjects = new CrmObjects();

        crmObjects.ServiceProvider = serviceProvider;
        crmObjects.TracingService =
            (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

        crmObjects.PluginContext = (IPluginExecutionContext)
            serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

        IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
        crmObjects.Service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(crmObjects.PluginContext.UserId);

        ExecutePluginLogic(crmObjects);
    }

    public virtual void ExecutePluginLogic(CrmObjects crmObjects)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I wrote a blog article about doing something similar, http://nicknow.net/dynamics-crm-2011-abstracting-plugin-setup/, a few years back. In the model I described it didn't rely on a base class but used a class that was instantiated on the first line of the `Execute` method to accomplish the same concept. I've since moved to a base class model - similar to this design. When I get a chance I'll put it out on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks Nick. This is indeed better.

Answer (score 2):

Also, even if you ever make your base class generic (maybe based on the type of context that it retrieves), you'll need to add the `: IPlugin` interface to all plugins, even though the base class defines it.